# Map function required to get an abs value of a given I/P

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Below is my sample code:-

```
def applyToEach(L, f):
  for i in range(len(L)):
    L[i] = f(L[i])

L = [1, -2, 3.333]
print('L = ', L)
print('Apply abs to each element of L.')
applyToEach(L, abs)
print('L = ', L)
```

Below is the O/p on the same:-

```
L =  [1, -2, 3.333]
L =  [1, 2, 3.333]
```

I would like to go for a map function that will modify my existing function applyToEach, so instead of using the one I used before, how can i use map function at applyToEach to get abs value of L?

Comment: Yeah. `map(abs, L)`

Comment: What's wrong with `L = list(map(abs, L))`? (by the way `L` is not an ideal name, lowercase more descriptive names are preferred). Or `L = [abs(x) for x in L]` for that matter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def applyToEach(L, f):
    L[:] = map(f, L)

L = [1, -2, 3.333]
print('L = ', L)
print('Apply abs to each element of L.')
applyToEach(L, abs)
print('L = ', L)
```

**Output:**

```
L =  [1, -2, 3.333]
Apply abs to each element of L.
L =  [1, 2, 3.333]
```

Answer (score 0):

use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function:

`map(abs, <your-list>)`

Answer (score 0):

`map` or a list comprehension will return a new object. You can't mutate existing object using those, but you can use this trick:

```
def applyToEach(L, f):
    my_list[:] = map(f, my_list)
```

or

```
my_list[:] = [f(i) for i in my_list]
```

these will modify `my_list` in place.

Comment: How should I call applyToEach to return the list

Comment: Do you want to return another list or modify the one passed? Your existing code does the latter.